# Retrieving image from css image sprites with images of different sizes

Tags: php, html, css

I'm aiming at doing a chess game or actually a chessengine just for the fun of it :-) The easy way to have several chesspieces would be to have one image for each chesspiece but that would be a lot of http-requests which seems unnecessary.

I want to use image from `https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg`

and retrieve the image with background-position and that would not be a problem...

BUT the issue is that the chessboard and it's square are not always the same size (it must be responsive) and I want each sprite to act as a normal image and resize accordingly to the squares.

I've tried with `background-size` and `background-size` and wrappers in combinations but obviously I'm missing out something. Maybe it's the wrong approach in this situation? What do you think?

I've also thought about "slicing" the sprite image and create the images from php but I think using css would be a nicer solution.

If I have like this html (which is generated from html) - I would like to view a scaled version of the chesspieces.png (which is 2000x667 in dimension) so it fits in this div and scales accordingly but only shows a portion of the chesspieces.png file, e.g. a rook. I hope you understand what I mean!?

```
<div style="float:left;background:#ffffff;
width:100px;height:100px;" 
class="square"><img src="chesspieces.png">
</div>
```

Please do tell if you need more information!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your input!

I've tried with this:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #ffffff 
url('chesspieces2000.png') -20% 40% no-repeat;background-size: cover; 
class="square"></div>
```

[image]
What ever I put in in y pos % it does not work. I want the image to fill out the whole square so therefore I'm using `background-size:cover`

I've also tried background-position-y:40% but nothing happens. I'm able to change ypos with fixed pixel values. Is this supposed to work in this way?

**Clarification:**

I have this output:
[image]

and with this html:

```
<div class="square" 
style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background:#000000"><div 
style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#000000 
url('chesspieces2000.png') 0 0 no-repeat;background-size:100%;" 
class="square"></div></div>
```

And I want to fetch one chesspiece scale it so it covers the square to 100% width and height auto.

**UPDATE2:**

Thanks to @Robo Robok Thanks!- I solved it, but some mixing with values made it work as I wanted to!

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;
background:#ffffff url('chesspieces2000.png') 19% -10% no-repeat;
background-size:auto 170%;"></div>
```

Here's the queen! :-)
[image]

and when resizing image wrapper:

---

**This works fine as well. It covers all the square!**

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;
background:#ffffff url('chesspieces2000.png') 20% 0% no-repeat;
background-size:auto 200%;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: background position / and size is typically how it's done.  Haven't used sprites in a long time.  (re. sliding doors)  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - it would be easy if width and height were the same, but with could also be like 70px or like 300px in the wrapper div.

Comment: That's fine, it makes it way harder.  But there is no issue with it.  `background-position: 100px 50px;` etc.  It's much easier if they are consistent width and consistent height.  The difference is you have to enter them manually instead of in a loop or something.  Make an object in JS `{king: [100,200], queen : [200,375]}` or what have you.

Comment: If it's not obvious, it has to be a background image, not an `img` tag. Then set the div to a fixed width, set the background to the image, set the position of the part you want.  Set no-repeat, etc. etc...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - I am not interested in using JS in this case. It's a chess engine that basically should just return value and not show them but I want to test the functionality.

Comment: If you use background-size and background-position with percentage values, then the size of your squares will not matter. Your sprites will be responsive : an old example from years ago used here https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Hezro

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - then don't use it, see if I care....  JS in not required, you just have to type them in the css then.  Also I took `it would be easy if width and height were the same` to mean the image parts were not the same size. Not the containers... As long as the image parts are consistent, it's not a big deal, just use `%` instead of pixel size

Comment: Sprites are better because you load 1 image, instead of having the "flash" effect as images load.  In the old days (before CSS3) that was very useful for rollovers etc.

Comment: I've updated some now for clarification what I'm looking for. Hope someone can help me/guide me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Just go with separate images. If you are super concerned about HTTP performance, just embed SVG images in your HTML.

Comment: @RoboRobok - Is what I am trying to achieve impossible? I'm just very curious. I'm not very concerned :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: url('chess.svg') no-repeat 40% 100%;
            background-size: auto 200%;"></div>
```

`background-size` needs to be `auto 200%`, because you have 2 rows in your sprite, which means the entire background needs to take twice the height of your element.

Background positions for each sprite are:

- First row: `0 0`, `20% 0`, `40% 0`, ... `100% 0`
- Second row: `0 100%`, `20% 100%`, `40% 100%`, ... `100% 100%`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working by mixing some of the values. I missed out on the auto-parameter in the background-size :-)

Comment: Tested with 100% instead of 200% as you wrote . Now I got it to 100% :-)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean. 100%?

Comment: I understand completely(100%)

Comment: I mean why did you replace 200% with 100%?